# button click temporarily changes div background color, not permanently as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I have a div which holds 2 input fields and buttons to change the background color of the div on click, the problem is when I click on the buttons(each one represents a color), the background color only changes for a flash of a second, not permanently

```
var noteCreate =
{
 noteCreateContainer : $("<article>", { id: "noteCreateContainer" }),
 noteForm : $("<form>", { id: "noteFormContainer" }),
 subjectField : $("<input>", { type: "text", placeholder: "Main Heading", id: "subject"}),
noteField : $("<input>", { type: "text", placeholder: "Enter your Note", id: "noteContent" }),
submitNote : $("<button>", { type: "submit", text: "post"}).click(saveFieldInput)
}

noteCreate.noteCreateContainer.appendTo("body");
noteCreate.noteForm.appendTo(noteCreateContainer);

//For each item in array create button
var noteColourArray = [];
noteColourArray[0] = "#03CEC2"; 
noteColourArray[1] = "#ADC607";
noteColourArray[2] = "#ffdd00";
noteColourArray[3] = "#f7941f";

//Loop through noteColourArray and create button for each item
for (var i = 0, len = noteColourArray.length; i < len; i++) {
 noteCreate.noteForm.append($("<button>", {class: "colourSelect", text: noteColourArray[i] }).click(setBackgroundColour)) 
 console.log(noteColourArray)
}

//Change background colour on click
function setBackgroundColour()
{
 $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[$(this).index()] )
}

noteCreate.subjectField.appendTo(noteFormContainer);
noteCreate.noteField.appendTo(noteFormContainer);
noteCreate.submitNote.appendTo(noteFormContainer);

//Run upon submitting note
//Create class div that shares variables, but each own background-color
function saveFieldInput()
{
//Read input from input fields when note is submitted
 var subjectInput = $("#subject").val();
 console.log(subjectInput);
}
```

UPDATE: I have added `return false` at the end of `function setBackgroundColour()` which seemed to get the result of what I seeked from this post, the colour buttons were never intended as form submit buttons, a separate button will take care of that

Comment: Try binding the `click` method with something like `$('.colourSelect').each(function() { $(this).on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); setBackgroundColour(); })});`

Comment: Something else must be changing the CSS back. Set an attribute modification breakpoint so you can see what it is.

Comment: could you possibly explain how that works? still quite new to javascript/jquery but like to understand

Comment: @NathanAnderson Your method of binding the click event should work fine.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure what would be changing the css, the setBackground function is the first time that div is being given a color

Comment: Yes, it's the first time it's being given a color. But something else is undoing that. I don't know what it could be, it's not in your code. That's why I suggested setting a breakpoint. When it fires, you can check the stack to see what's doing it.

Comment: @NathanAnderson, your colour is changing back as you are posting a form so the page will reload.  The `e.preventDefault` stops the form from posting back and thus the page won't be reset

Comment: before I can fully know if this works, the one thing the suggested .each loop doesn't do that my for loop did was create buttons for each array item, I not sure how to bring that back in with your code @techouse

Comment: Posted it as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i in noteColourArray) {
    // build the button with pure JS just cause it's faster
    var button = document.createElement('button'),
        buttonText = document.createTextNode(noteColourArray[i]);
    button.className = 'colourSelect';
    button.appendChild(buttonText);

    // append the button
    noteCreate.noteForm.append(button);
}
$('.colourSelect').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[index]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I wrote this slightly differently but I'll mark it as the answer because the problem was that I was missing that e.preventDefault, thanks for the help