# LocalStorage retrieving from arrays, confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Getting confused, creating a web app where people post notes, I have a field for subject and one for the actual note, when posted these should be saved into two arrays, when posted these should appear almost like a comment, with what you just entered in two fields, which did work but I want people to be able to save their notes, close the browser and return, below is the code that is not working, basically the user should be able to

Allow user to enter in values. 
 
If local storage is available, Take values saved from arrays (which I tried converting to a string then convert back to a array using JSON, which is confusing) and fill the page

```
$("document").ready( function (){

//Each subjectField.value goes into array
var subjectInputArray = [];
//Each noteField.value goes into array
var noteInputArray = [];

//Color array holds color hex codes as values
var noteColourArray = [];
noteColourArray[0] = "#03CEC2"; 
noteColourArray[1] = "#ADC607";
noteColourArray[2] = "#ffdd00";
noteColourArray[3] = "#f7941f";

//Variable holds properties for note creation
var noteCreate =
    {
        noteCreateContainer : $("<article>", { id: "noteCreateContainer" }),
        noteForm : $("<form>", { id: "noteFormContainer" }),
        subjectField : $("<input>", { type: "text", placeholder: "Title", id: "subject"}),
        noteField : $("<input>", { type: "text", placeholder: "Write a Note", id: "noteContent" }),
        submitNote : $("<button>", { type: "submit", id: "post", text: "post"}).on( "click", (postNote))
    }

//Variable holds properties for a note content (NOT SUBJECT);
var notePost = {}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

//Test if local storage is supported
if( Modernizr.localstorage ) {

    //Get current array/list
    localStorage.getItem("subjectInputArray")

    //Convert string back to array
    var savedNoteSubjects = JSON.parse(localStorage["subjectInputArray"]); 

    //For each item in subject localStorage array, loop through an fill page with fields containing values
    for(var i = 0; i < savedNoteSubjects.length; i++)
    {
        //Create container for post
        //Apply noteCreateContainer's selected background color to the posted note
        $("<article>").appendTo("body").addClass("notePostContainer").css("background-color", ($("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color"))); 
        console.log("local storage: " + [savedNoteSubjects]);

        //Select last div of class notePostContainer to add input field, instead of adding 1+ input fields on each click to all classes using the same class name
        $("<input>", {class: "subjectFieldPost", type: "text", value: savedNoteSubjects[savedNoteSubjects.length-1] }).appendTo(".notePostContainer:last-child").prop("disabled", true);
    }
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support localStorage, consider upgrading your internet browser");
}   

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Create/Set up fields required for user to input data
noteCreate.noteCreateContainer.prependTo("body");
noteCreate.noteForm.appendTo(noteCreateContainer);
//Loop through noteColourArray and append new button for each item
for (var i = 0, len = noteColourArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    noteCreate.noteForm.append($("<button>", {class: "colourSelect", value: noteColourArray[i] }).css("background-color", noteColourArray[i]).click(setBackgroundColour)) 
}
//Change background colour on click
function setBackgroundColour()
{
    $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[$(this).index()] )
    return false;
}
noteCreate.subjectField.appendTo(noteFormContainer);
noteCreate.noteField.appendTo(noteFormContainer);
noteCreate.submitNote.appendTo(noteFormContainer);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------BELOW NOTE POST/OUTPUT FROM CREATING NOTE

//FUNCTION - CREATE NEW POST UPON CLICKING POST
function postNote()
{
    //Add submitted value of subject field to array
    subjectInputArray.push( $("#subject").val() );

    //Convert array into string
    localStorage["subjectInputArray"] = JSON.stringify(subjectInputArray);

    //Add value of note field to array
    noteInputArray.push( $("#noteContent").val() );

    //Create container for post
    $("<article>").appendTo("body").addClass("notePostContainer").css("background-color", ($(noteCreateContainer).css("background-color")) ) //Apply noteCreateContainer's selected background color to the posted note

    //Select last div of class notePostContainer to add input field, instead of adding 1+ input fields on each click to all classes using the same class name
    //Pull value from local storage subject array
    $("<input>", {class: "subjectFieldPost", type: "text", value: subjectInputArray[subjectInputArray.length-1] }).appendTo(".notePostContainer:last-child").prop("disabled", true)

    //Select last div of class notePostContainer to add input field, instead of adding 1+ input fields on each click to all classes using the same class name
    $("<input>", {class: "noteFieldPost", type: "text", value: noteInputArray[noteInputArray.length-1] }).appendTo(".notePostContainer:last-child").prop("disabled", true)
    return false;
} //End function
```

});

An earlier post I made in relation to my idea
[button click temporarily changes div background color, not permanently as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511734/button-click-temporarily-changes-div-background-color-not-permanently-as-intend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var subjectInputArray = [];
...
localStorage["subjectInputArray"] = JSON.stringify(subjectInputArray);
```

You are setting your `localStorage["subjectInputArray"]` to an empty array every time your page loads.

How could you expect load anything useful from it?

Instead, try put `localStorage["subjectInputArray"] = JSON.stringify(subjectInputArray);` in `postNote()`, so every time user input something, you update the localStorage record.

Additionally,

```
var savedNoteSubjects = JSON.parse(localStorage["subjectInputArray"]);
```

this line should be inside the test local storage if block. Don't use it until it's confirmed to be available

Comment: the other thing i'm confused on is when I append a field taking the last entered value from a array, do I still target subjectInputArray or the variable savedNoteSubjects (in the value for the fields to be appended, in postNote), thats where i'm getting myself confused @Mark Ni

Comment: @NathanAnderson To make your life easier, I suggest you just assign `savedNoteSubjects` to `subjectInputArray` using `subjectInputArray = savedNotesSubjects` after load it from localstorage. You only need one array to work with.

Comment: ive got it partially working on your advice, the local storage is kinda working except im overwriting the array, if i refresh the page it gives me my last entered value instead of all of them which was the intention of the for loop @Mark Ni

Comment: I'ma have to ask if you can further help me @Mark Ni, im rather new to local storage, I've fiddled with just about everything and can not figure out why when I refresh my page to make sure the values have stayed, it only saves the last entered value, its like it wipes everything in the array except for one value, much appreciated the help so far

Comment: For now I've just changed the above code with the newer version @Mark Ni

Comment: @NathanAnderson like I said above, you need assign the old array you loaded to `subjectInputArray` first. Otherwise, you new `subjectInputArray` won't have these old values when you save it again to localstorage.

Comment: do you mean right up at the top where Ive said var subjectInputArray = [] ?

Comment: @NathanAnderson no. you saved your array by `localStorage["subjectInputArray"] = JSON.stringify(subjectInputArray);`, so when you load it you put it right back into where it belongs before : `subjectInputArray = JSON.parse(localStorage["subjectInputArray"]); ` In the load from localstorage block.